# JavaScript RegEx for this pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want RegEx for testing a string like '00:00 AM' for these requirements.

1. first digit can be 1 to 12.
2. then a colon.
3. a digit from 0 to 59
4. then a space.
5. then 'AM' or 'PM'

and use it like

`EXP.test('00:00 AM') //true
EXP.test('13:70 CM') //false`

can anybody help?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

A simple expression would be:

1. `(0[0-9]|1[012])` - *Either 00-09 or 10-12*
2. `\:` - *Colon*
3. `[0-5][0-9]` - *00 - 59*
4. - *Space*
5. `[AP]M` - *Either AM or PM*

Combined that would be:

```
/(0[0-9]|1[012])\:([0-5][0-9]) [AP]M/g
```

Make sense?

Comment: Did you actually test your regex?

Comment: @KevBot According to OP, his requirement luckily does not include single digits, as evident in `00:00`

Comment: Try 12:00 PM :)